# How to format calculated number in siunitx within tikz?

Tags: formatting, siunitx

I have created a macro that draws a triangle with a given height. I would like the three base lengths to be formatted as 5, 5.4 and 6 respectively. What is the best way to achieve this? Wold it be within `tikz` or `siunitx`? I did try something from `tikz` but then my file didn't compile.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\newcommand{\triangleSHS}[4][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm,#1]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\path (O) ++(0:#2) coordinate (X);
\path (X) ++(90:#3) coordinate (B);
\path (X) ++(0:#4) coordinate (A);
\pgfmathparse{add(#2,#4)}
\draw (O)--node[below]{\SI{\pgfmathresult}{\centi\metre}}(A)--(B)--(O); 
\draw[dashed] (X)--node[right]{\SI{#3}{\centi\metre}}(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
}%


\begin{document}

\triangleSHS{2}{4}{3}

\triangleSHS{2.1}{4.2}{3.3}

\triangleSHS{2.5}{4}{3.5}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the rounding capabilities of siunitx:

You just have to pass a few options:

1. `round-mode=places`. Will set the rounding precision to the number of decimal places.
2. `round-precision=1`. This, with the previous options, will give you one decimal place.
3. `zero-decimal-to-integer`. This one will round the `5.0` to `5` to give what you want.

You can pass the options locally to `\SI` with:

```
\SI[round-mode=places, round-precision=1,zero-decimal-to-integer]{\pgfmathresult}{\centi\metre}
```

or globally with:

```
\sisetup{round-mode=places, round-precision=1,zero-decimal-to-integer}
```

and then:

```
 \SI{\pgfmathresult}{\centi\metre}
```

Code with the options set locally:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Global configuration:
% \sisetup{round-mode=places, round-precision=1,zero-decimal-to-integer}

\newcommand{\triangleSHS}[4][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm,#1]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\path (O) ++(0:#2) coordinate (X);
\path (X) ++(90:#3) coordinate (B);
\path (X) ++(0:#4) coordinate (A);
\pgfmathparse{add(#2,#4)}
\draw (O)--node[below]{\SI[round-mode=places, round-precision=1,zero-decimal-to-integer]{\pgfmathresult}{\centi\metre}}(A)--(B)--(O); 
\draw[dashed] (X)--node[right]{\SI{#3}{\centi\metre}}(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
}%


\begin{document}

\triangleSHS{2}{4}{3}

\triangleSHS{2.1}{4.2}{3.3}

\triangleSHS{2.5}{4}{3.5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was too slow :(

Comment: @Skillmon I know the fell, I've been there too U_U

Comment: Yeah, but normally it's egreg being faster than you, that is acceptable...