# crop region outside a path

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

this is the first time i code with tikz and i'm stuck in trying to delete everything outside the path drawn in black. Can anyone help me?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {-15,-14.5,-14,-13.5,-13,-12.5,-12,-11.5,-11,-10.5,-10,-9.5,-9,-8.5,-8,-7.5,-7,-6.5,-6,-5.5,-5,-4.5,-4,-3.5,-3,-2.5,-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5,9,9.5,10,10.5,11,11.5,12,12.5,13,13.5,14,14.5}
        {
            \foreach \y in {-15,-14.5,-14,-13.5,-13,-12.5,-12,-11.5,-11,-10.5,-10,-9.5,-9,-8.5,-8,-7.5,-7,-6.5,-6,-5.5,-5,-4.5,-4,-3.5,-3,-2.5,-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5,9,9.5,10,10.5,11,11.5,12,12.5,13,13.5,14,14.5}
            {
                   \node[draw,circle,gray,inner sep=1.5pt,fill] at (.56002*\x,.56002*\y) {};
             }  
        }
    \begin{scope}[rotate=1]
        \foreach \x in {-13.5,-13,-12.5,-12,-11.5,-11,-10.5,-10,-9.5,-9,-8.5,-8,-7.5,-7,-6.5,-6,-5.5,-5,-4.5,-4,-3.5,-3,-2.5,-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5,9,9.5,10,10.5,11,11.5,12,12.5,13}
        {
             \foreach \y in {-13.5,-13,-12.5,-12,-11.5,-11,-10.5,-10,-9.5,-9,-8.5,-8,-7.5,-7,-6.5,-6,-5.5,-5,-4.5,-4,-3.5,-3,-2.5,-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5,9,9.5,10,10.5,11,11.5,12,12.5,13}
                {
                   \node[draw,circle,red,inner sep=1.5pt,fill] at (.600*\x,.6000*\y) {};
             }  
        }
    \end{scope}
    \path [draw,ultra thick, black] (-4,-8) -- (4,-3.0717) -- (4,6.92) -- (-4,2) -- (-4,-8);  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: search `inverse clip`

Comment: @Symbol1 The OP says _delete everything outside the path_, maybe an ordinary `clip` is enough.

Comment: @CarLaTeX you are right...

Comment: @Symbol1 The title is misleading :):):)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go `:)`

[image]

I took the liberty to simplify your code a little.

When using `\foreach`, you can use the following syntax:

```
\foreach \x in {start,start+1,...,end}
```

The loop will iterate from `start` to `end` with the step given by the difference of `start` and `start+1`.

To remove everything outside the path you use the `\clip` commmand.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (-4,-8) -- (4,-3.0717) -- (4,6.92) -- (-4,2) -- cycle;
        \foreach \x in {-15,-14.5,...,14.5}
        {
            \foreach \y in {-15,-14.5,...,14.5}
            {
                   \node [draw,circle,gray,inner sep=1.5pt,fill] at (.56002*\x,.56002*\y) {};
             }  
        }
    \begin{scope}[rotate=1]
        \foreach \x in {-13.5,-13,...,13}
        {
             \foreach \y in {-13.5,-13,...,13}
                {
                   \node[draw,circle,red,inner sep=1.5pt,fill] at (.600*\x,.6000*\y) {};
             }  
        }
    \end{scope}
    \path [draw,ultra thick, black] (-4,-8) -- (4,-3.0717) -- (4,6.92) -- (-4,2) -- (-4,-8);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(Nice picture! `:)`)

Comment: You beat me by a minute :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX It [happens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412759/how-to-format-calculated-number-in-siunitx-within-tikz/412760#comment1030542_412760) `:)`

Comment: You are very fast!

Comment: Sometimes... Grazie :)

Comment: thanks! Didn't know that loop syntax would have worked also for non integer so i generate the sequence with bash seq...
Now i need to place that figure in a tex file (my theses :P) and i copied the code in the tex instead a \begin{figure}\centering ... \end{figure}. Do you suggest any smartest way also to manage figure dimension?