# How to show more decimal digits with siunitx package?

Tags: siunitx, unit-of-measure, decimal-number

I use the following code to write a physical quantity:

```
\SI[]{14.351368}{\deg}
```

The problem is that I get only two decimal digits instead of six.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: without a fully working example it is impossible to know what you are doing wrong. by default siunitx doesn't reformat numbers. So something in you document is making it do so.

Comment: Do you have an instruction such as `\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=2}` somewhere in your document?

Comment: Unrelated, with recent `siunitx` package (version 3) you should write `\qty{14.351368}{\deg}`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format calculated number in siunitx within tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412759/how-to-format-calculated-number-in-siunitx-within-tikz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, I've solved by using the option:
`[round-precision = 5]`